# Elements running from the viewport perimeter, is there a name for that functionality?

Tags: interaction-design, web-app, html

So you know how if you right click on your desktop, the menu will appear either at the top-left, top-right, bottom-left, bottom-right depending on where your cursor is on the page? (`<select>` elements do the same.)

Is there a name for that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The menu you're talking about is a contextual menu. 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context_menu

I believe the type of positioning you're talking about is called **relative positioning**

Comment: I think I will call it "Relative Displacement". :)

Thanks for the article!